# how do I convert wpf dispatcher to winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dispatcher

I was moving over a method to my winforms project from a wpf project.

Everything but this section was moved without issue:

```
private void ServerProcErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  // You have to do this through the Dispatcher because this method is called by a different Thread
  Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
  {
    richTextBox_Console.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
    richTextBox_Console.SelectionStart = richTextBox_Console.Text.Length;
    richTextBox_Console.ScrollToCaret();
    ParseServerInput(e.Data);
  }));
}
```

I have no idea how to convert over `Dispatcher` to winforms.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: *If your WPF code translates well enough to winforms, most probably you're doing it wrong. winforms' databindings capabilities are really limited compared to WPF's*

Comment: @HighCore Sometimes, you have no choice about the technology you have to use

Comment: @Shimrod <-- has it right.

Comment: @Shimrod I didn't say anything about the technology. I'm saying well-formed WPF code is fundamentally different from winforms code.

Comment: @HighCore the C# code moved over just fine... not sure what the problem is?

Comment: @HighCore: Ok, but what does that have to do with anything?  He has to make the translation.  What's your point?  It's not like converting WPF to WinForms requires some brilliant technological insight.

Comment: I didn't mean to offence you, *"winforms' databindings capabilities are really limited compared to WPF's"* sounded a bit dogmatic.  But I understand your point of view now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to replace the `Dispatcher`.

```
private void ServerProcErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox_Console.InvokeRequired)
    {
        richTextBox_Console.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ServerProcErrorDataReceived(sender, e);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox_Console.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
        richTextBox_Console.SelectionStart = richTextBox_Console.Text.Length;
        richTextBox_Console.ScrollToCaret();
        ParseServerInput(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: More specifically use the `Invoke` method on `richTextBox_Console`.